# wp_schedule_single_event() not creating wp-cron job but executed successfully

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, wordpress-hook

I am using the `wp_schedule_single_event()` function to create a wp-cron job that sends an email to the specified user at the specified time.

Mostly this wp-cron job is successfully created and the users get informed in time. But sometimes it just doesn't work.

Whats especially strange is that `wp_schedule_single_event()` always returns `true` (which means that it was executed successfully) even when the wp-cron job isn't created (I check that with the WP Crontrol plugin).

My code (write_log: custom function to log the given strings, time: the corresponding timestamp):

```
write_log('User ' . get_current_user_id() . ' now tries to create the addProductsExpired cron job with timestamp: ' . time);
$success = wp_schedule_single_event(time, 'hook_addProductsExpired', array(get_current_user_id()));
if (!$success) {
    write_log('The creation failed!'); 
}
write_log('User ' . get_current_user_id() . ' now tries to create the sendReminderMail cron job with timestamp: ' . time);
$success = wp_schedule_single_event(time - 60 * 60 * 24, 'hook_sendReminderMail', array(get_current_user_id()));
if (!$success) {
    write_log('The creation failed!');
}
```

I should also note that I never accomplished it to reproduce the error by myself

I so far tried:

- updating Wordpress
- studying the logs
- executing the function with accounts of users where it previously failed (it worked on my pc and also on the pc of the user in future executions)
- modifying parameters in the user entry of affected users
- manually executing the function with the parameters it previously failed
- rewriting and optimising the whole function

None of them worked or threw an error i could debug.

Comment: Perhaps use AS: https://actionscheduler.org/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am now using [actionsheduler.org](https://actionscheduler.org) as suggested by Terminator-Barbapapa
in his comment to my question. So far I haven't experienced any issues.